# What is the tool/command to check internet routing to a website?

Tags: linux, networking

I recall there is a linux command to show the network route from your ip to the destination website. Right now I am on windows. Does anyone know the command? A similar tool will work too.

Answer (score 1):

tracert in Windows.

```
C:\Users\phantom>tracert www.google.com

Tracing route to www.google.com [172.217.4.36]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.18.96.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms     4 ms  10.0.247.65
  3     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.241.209
  4    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.241.122
  5     2 ms     1 ms     7 ms  10.47.116.5
  6     6 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  172.30.99.8
  7    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  172.30.249.100
  8    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  65.247.121.251
  9     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  67.148.245.93
 10    12 ms    12 ms    14 ms  cer-edge-22.inet.qwest.net [205.171.139.18]
 11    15 ms    12 ms    12 ms  208.47.121.146
 12    11 ms    12 ms    11 ms  108.170.243.193
 13    12 ms    12 ms    13 ms  216.239.47.129
 14    12 ms    11 ms    13 ms  lga15s46-in-f4.1e100.net [172.217.4.36]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: That may not give the actual path for TCP because it uses ICMP. Also, many ISPs will look for a traceroute and send it via a different path in order to hide internal routing. ICMP and TCP could be sent via different paths.